# Posting an image to foursquare by URL?

Tags: rest, api, foursquare, photo-upload

Looking through the [Foursquare documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/) I found the [Photo Add](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/photos/add) section.

In APIs for other social platforms I have been able to post an image by its source url, e.g.: `https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png` (e.g. this is possible on Facebook & Tumblr)

The documentation is a little unclear about the capabilities of the `post*` developer preview argument.

Is it possible to "upload" an image by its source url to Foursquare?

(otherwise can I get this added to the feature request queue?!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to upload an image by url. You will need to upload the image data with your photos/add request.

Comment: Okay well would I be able to request this feature be added?

Comment: You can send API feedback to api@foursquare.com